# MPAndroidChart Bar chart start from non zero Y or Column Range chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart for drawing a Combined graph (with a bar chart and line chart).

I want to display a "Column Range Chart" -  a bar chart whose starting point will be variable for each entries, as shown in the below image,

[image: Column Range chart]

How is it possible to achieve this using MPAndroidChart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `CandleStickChart`. It's main purpose it to show financial data.
Your problem might be with highest/lowest (shadow) open or closing values, it might require to play with them to achieve what you want.

A quick sample:

```
CandleStickChart candleStickChart = (CandleStickChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);</p>
ArrayList<CandleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>
entries.add(new CandleEntry(0, 2.70f, 4.13f, 2.70f, 4.13f));
entries.add(new CandleEntry(1, 3.35f, 4.96f, 3.35f, 4.96f));
entries.add(new CandleEntry(2, 3.50f, 4.50f, 3.50f, 4.50f));
entries.add(new CandleEntry(3, 4.40f, 5.0f, 4.40f, 5.0f));
entries.add(new CandleEntry(4, 2.80f, 4.5f, 2.80f, 4.5f));
```

Notice that second/fourth third/fifth parameter in `CandleEntry` constructor are the same to eliminate shadow values.

Tutorial on how to use it is [here](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-candlestick-chart-using-mpandroidchart-library-tutorial/)

More info:
You might have a problem with drawing vertical data values, this might not be possible.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it really helped me. Vertical values does not matter, its just a screenshot.

Comment: @GokulKulkarni I have a similar requirement but in my case it doesn't plot the y axis with my data as it is. I have set second/fourth third/fifth parameter in CandleEntry constructor to same but does not work

Comment: @channae I am sorry to say I have moved out of android, now I am working on react-native, so I am afraid I will not be able to help u

Comment: @GokulKulkarni Appreciate your response. I managed to fix the issue. Apparently it is a bug in the library. Axis left shows correct values while axis right dimens are different unless you enable both axis then it works fine. So I enabled and configured both axis and then changed visibility in the left axis to get the right axis working. Now its values are perfectly fitting with the chart. Thanks anyways!