# MPAndroidChart BarChart bars getting cut off

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart for drawing a chart in my Android App.

One requirement is I need to bar chart starting from non-zero y position, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764176/mpandroidchart-bar-chart-start-from-non-zero-y-or-column-range-chart). So I had using CandleStickChart for the same.
Now my bars are getting cut off at the start and end.

Is there any way to give padding at the start and end of the graph so that it does not get cut off.

Note: My XAxis values are like "4Nov", "5Nov"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying many things, I found out this solution,

`graph.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(candleData.getXMax() + 0.25f);`
`graph.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(candleData.getXMin() - 0.25f);`

Comment: Thanks for the trying! I was looking for solution for the same problem.

Comment: I the inverse of this setting to proposital cut off the sides of my chart and give it a sense of infinity by hiding the first and last values and displaying only 3 of my set of 5 in the center.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is increasing the SpaceTop value.

```
var yaxis = chart.AxisLeft;
yaxis.SpaceTop = 1.35f;
```